# Power BI Custom Visual: having a property panel for each column

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm developing a Power BI custom visual that displays a simple table, each column of the table is defined by a field (grouping or measure) that can be added to the fields panel of the visual, just like a normal native Power BI table. Here's the definition in my `capabilities.json` file:

```
"dataRoles": [
    {
        "displayName": "Table Data",
        "name": "data",
        "kind": "GroupingOrMeasure"
    }
]
```

Now, what I would like to do is have a dedicated section in the "format" panel for each column, in other words: for each field that is added to the visual. This would allow me to customize each column separately, for example by assigning a color or custom header to each one.

Here's an example of what I'd like (made in photoshop):

[image]

However, I've been reading the documentation but I can't find any examples on how to do this. I've read about data-bound properties, but the docs are incredibly vague, so much that I'm not even sure that is the right approach, let alone how to actually implement it.

Are there any examples on how to do this? Can it even be done at all?

Answer (score 1):

More of an FYI than an answer but this may still be useful...

The [new format pane](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-the-new-format-pane-preview/) handles this by keeping the controls in one section but allows you to switch between columns using a dropdown:

[image: Format pane screenshot]

For any column you pick, you can adjust the formatting individually:

[image]

Comment: This is very interesting, but can I customize the menu for each column by adding my own settings? That's the key when developing a custom visual, I need to save some specific per-column setting that are not the usual formatting ones.

Comment: I haven't explored much of the world of custom visuals yet, so your guess is at least as good as mine. Best wishes on your journey!